# Importing custom CommonJS module fails

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a CommonJS module in project A in the following way:

```js
const { WebElement } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { By } = require('selenium-webdriver');

class VlElement extends WebElement {
    constructor(driver, selector) {
        ...
    }

    async getClassList() {
        ...
    }
}

module.exports = VlElement;
```

In project B I use the following code:

```js
const VlElement = require('projectA');

class VlButton extends VlElement {  
    constructor(driver, selector) {
        super(driver, selector);
    }
    ...
}

module.exports = VlButton;
```

When running the code, VLElemlent cannot be found.
It is in my `package.json` and I can see VLElement under `projectB > node_modules > projectA`.
What am I doing wrong with my exports?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: Make sure you have a projectB/mode_modules/package.json with a `main` which points to the file that defines/exports `VlElement`.

Comment: @Michael I do not have that, but I have multiple files I need to get exported. Do I make an index.js and export all the files I need in that one?

Comment: That's more complicated :) I wrote you an answer for it. I don't know for sure this is your problem, but you should know this anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a `projectB/mode_modules/package.json` with a `main` which points to the file that defines/exports `VlElement`, like this:

```
  "main": "path/to/file/with/VlElement.js",
```

When you call `require('projectA');` this has to be resolved to a file inside projectA so that it can be evaluated to (and return) the exports from that file. The `main` entry in the `package.json` allows this (but defaults to `index.js`, so if you are using that you don't need `package.json`, probably, but you should have it anyway).

You can have multiple files with various exports, but remember `require('projectA');` can still only return one thing, so the way to do that is usually to have an `index.js` which looks something like:

```js
module.exports = {
    'something': require('./something.js'),
    'otherthing': require('./otherthing.js'),
    'etc': require('./etc.js'),
};
```